# Why does Firebug show duplicate $_POST requests?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I've had this problem for a while: When I use jquery `$.post`, I see LOTS of requests in the Firebug console that are exactly the same, and only the last one returns anything. If I click on the plus sign to open the tree for any of the other requests, it shifts the console about 1px but is totally blank. The loading images in the console don't go away.

The image shown is the result of a single `$.post` action in Firebug 1.6.2, Mozilla Firefox 3.6.16 on Windows 7.

[image: Firebug Console showing duplicate requests]

The action only executes once and returns one result, in other words it behaves normally. Is there an explanation for this, or is something awry with my code?

Even this code will trigger multiple requests in the console:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('/', {}, function(){
        alert('ok');
    }, "json");
});
```

And the form:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
<div>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="id">
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I checked this out in Firebug Lite on Chrome (no problems), and eventually upgraded to Firefox 4 and Firebug 1.7. No more issues. I "re-google" the subject about once a month to see if it pops up and never once did I hear it reported. So, issue resolved... I guess (Although I miss FF3 already!). I have been dealing with this for at least a year, so I'm still interested in hearing if anyone else has experienced this.

Answer (score 4):

That usually means that your client-side code actually is triggering all those individual requests, but only the last one is completing (possibly due to how your server-side handles simultaneous requests from the same session).  Can you post the code that's triggering your `$.post`()?

Comment: That's bizarre that it turned out to be Firefox or Firebug itself.  I've never seen that myself (using that same combo of FF/FB myself at one point).  Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Yeah it's strange. What's stranger is that many months ago it used to show 2-3 extra requests, then 5-6,  but when I saw the one in the picture I decided that was enough - time to seek help. I figured I was making some god-awful scripting error that was getting compounded by the newer code.